# SQL Help - If Then Else

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I need the help of someone who understands SQL better than I do...
I am trying to make a single SP call that uses the IF THEN ELSE but keep getting three "the multi-part identifier  could not be bound" messages.

Pages can be sponsored by a Business or a Group.
In the advertEntityType field I have a "B" or a "G" for business or group.
In the advertEntityID field I have the businessID or groupID.

```
SELECT
   Advertisements.advertEntityType
  ,Advertisements.advertEntityID
FROM Advertisements
WHERE Advertisements.advertPageName = @pageName

IF (Advertisements.advertEntityType = 'G')

    SELECT
      Group.groupID
     ,Group.groupName
     ,Group.groupPhone
     ,Group.groupWebsite
     ,Group.groupLogoName
    FROM Group
    WHERE Group.groupID = Advertisements.advertEntityID

ELSE

    SELECT
      Business.businessID
     ,Business.businessName
     ,Business.businessWorkPhone
     ,Business.businessWebsite
     ,Business.businessLogoName
    FROM Business
    WHERE Business.businessID = Advertisements.advertEntityID
```

When I try to execute I get these messages which I cannot seem to get my head around...

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Sponsor_s01, Line 36
The multi-part identifier "Advertisements.advertEntityType" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Sponsor_s01, Line 46
The multi-part identifier "Advertisements.advertEntityID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Sponsor_s01, Line 58
The multi-part identifier "Advertisements.advertEntityID" could not be bound.
```

Comment: Could you please specify the RDBMS that you are using (sql server, mysql, postgresql, ...)?

Comment: He's using SQL Server, as evident by the error messages he's getting: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-4104.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Advertisements.advertEntityType` is a table name and column name. You need to assign these values to local variables if you want to use them in if statements. If I understand correctly you want to evaluate based on the condition in the first select statement. In this case you should use such query:

```
DECLARE @entityType int --assuming the type of Advertisements.advertEntityType is int
DECLARE @advertEntityID int  --assuming the type of Advertisements.advertEntityID is int

SELECT
    @entityType = Advertisements.advertEntityType,
    @advertEntityID = Advertisements.advertEntityID
FROM Advertisements
WHERE Advertisements.advertPageName = @pageName

IF (@entityType = 'G')
    SELECT
        Group.groupID
       ,Group.groupName
       ,Group.groupPhone
       ,Group.groupWebsite
       ,Group.groupLogoName
    FROM Group
    WHERE Group.groupID = @advertEntityID
ELSE
    SELECT
        Business.businessID
       ,Business.businessName
       ,Business.businessWorkPhone
       ,Business.businessWebsite
       ,Business.businessLogoName
    FROM Business
    WHERE Business.businessID = @advertEntityID
```